# How to copy files with a particular extension from one directory to another in linux

Tags: linux, shell

I am newbie in Linux. I have to write a *shell script* which accepts user input ("file extension" and "destination") and copy files from one directory to  destination directory.

How to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

myscript.sh

```
#/bin/sh
EXT=${1}
DST=${2}
cp *.$EXT "$DST"
```

Ex:

$ myscript.sh cpp /home/user/

Copies files with .cpp extension in current directory to /home/user directory

Comment: Here is my code: echo "Enter the type(extension) of files "
read type
echo "Enter the destination"
read destination
cp *."$type""$destination"

Comment: Giving 
cp: missing destination file operand after â*.txt/home/ubuntu/testfolderâ
exception

Comment: echo "Enter the type(extension) of files " 
read type 
echo "Enter the destination" 
read destination 
cp *."$type" "$destination"

Comment: You missed space between $type and $destination

Comment: still giving exception :(

Comment: Exception is: cp: target âhome/ubuntu/txtDirectoryâ is not a directory

Comment: It means the destination you are giving is not a directory

Comment: There is a directory called "txtDirectory". I am running the prog as ./copyfiles txt /home/ubuntu/txtDirectory